# Pydantic 2 model validate optional field

Tags: python-3.x, pydantic

I have the problem. I generate the dynamic model with every optional fields and I want to validate model with get information about missing fields.

```py
from pydantic import create_model, model_validator, ValidationInfo
from typing import Any, Union

def my_model_validator(cls, v: Any, info: ValidationInfo) -> Any:
    data_set = set([k for k, _ in v.items()])
    model_set = set([k for k, _ in cls.model_fields.items()])
    diff = model_set - data_set
    if diff:
        print(f"Checker. Needed {len(model_set)} and Get {len(data_set)}.")
    return v


def main():
    data_for_create_model = [
        {"name": "field_a", "type": int},
        {"name": "field_b", "type": str},
        {"name": "field_c", "type": bool},
    ]
    temp_fields = {}
    for el in data_for_create_model:
        temp_fields.setdefault(f'{el["name"]}', (Union[el["type"], None], None))

    temp_validators: dict = {
        "model_validator": model_validator(mode="before")(my_model_validator)
    }
    temp_model = create_model(
        "temp_model",
        **temp_fields,
        __validators__=temp_validators,
    )

    data_for_validate_1 = {"field_a": 1, "field_b": "1", "field_c": True}
    pydantic_model_1 = temp_model(**data_for_validate_1)
    print(pydantic_model_1)

    data_for_validate_2 = {"field_a": 1, "field_b": "1"}
    pydantic_model_2 = temp_model(**data_for_validate_2)
    print(pydantic_model_2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Response

```bash
field_a=1 field_b='1' field_c=True
Checker. Needed 3 and Get 2.
field_a=1 field_b='1' field_c=None
```

How I can return information about missing field due model validation without raising ValidationError?

I read about validation context, but it's not return anything data. Maybe somebody solved this problem before.